# jmeter start in no pause mode from command line

Tags: command-line, timer, jmeter

I have a test plan in JMeter using some Timers.

In some situations I would like to execute the test plan from the command line with all Timers disabled (Same as with the Menu Option "Start no pause"), is it possible to use this option from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as of jmeter 2.13.
You should open an enhancement request.

A possible way to do it is to make timers use a property as pause and pass it as command line property with:

> -JmyPauseProperty=0

**Edit 10 may 2015:**

You created bugzilla enhancement:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57912

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will open an enhancement request.
The proposed solution is a possibility but as I have several timers with different values it means I will have to declare a property for each of them.